# Angular SSR cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm redirecting the page on SSR to another URL based on some conditions in component TS file. The issue is that after this redirect the node code will still continue running and a setHeader function will run which causes this error.
I don't have any access in server.ts file to know that the page is already redirected to bypass the setHeader function.

I redirect on app.component.ts file and the setHeader function is in server.ts file.